# Выведение значение объекта во View.Bag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Есть абстрактный класс, наследник и контроллер. Мне в строке  **"ViewBag.Text = devicesDictionary[id].Status; // Не могу здесь вывести состояние объекта [id] студия подчеркивает красным The name 'id' does not exist in the current context"** необходимо вывести строковое значение статуса. Но devicesDictionary[id].Status не могу применить. Как можно решить вывод строки?

```
public abstract class Device : IStatus
{
    private bool status;
    public Device()
    {

    }
    public Device(bool status, string name)
    {
        Status = status;
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Status
    {
        get
        {
            return status;
        }
        set
        {
            status = value;
        }
    }
    public virtual void OnDevice()
    {
        if (Status == false)
        {
            status = true;
        }
    }
    public virtual void OffDevice()
    {
        if (Status)
        {
            status = false;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string status;
        if (this.status)
        {
            status = "Включено";
        }
        else
        {
            status = "Выключено";
        }
        return status;
    }
}   
  public class Lamp : Device, ILampMode
{
    private BrightnessLevel level;
    public Lamp(bool status, string name, BrightnessLevel level)
        : base(status, name)
    {
        this.level = level;
    }
    public BrightnessLevel Level
    {
        get
        {
            return level;
        }
    }
    public void SetLowBrightness()
    {
        if (Status)
        {
            level = BrightnessLevel.Low;
        }
    }
    public void SetMediumBrightness()
    {
        if (Status)
        {
            level = BrightnessLevel.Medium;
        }
    }
    public void SetHighBrightness()
    {
        if (Status)
        {
            level = BrightnessLevel.High;
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string mod;
        if (level == BrightnessLevel.Low)
        {
            mod = "Низкий";
        }
        else if (level == BrightnessLevel.Medium)
        {
            mod = "Средний";
        }
        else if (level == BrightnessLevel.High)
        {
            mod = "Высокий";
        }
        else
        {
            mod = "Не задан";
        }
        return base.ToString() + "<br />" + "Режим яркости: " + mod.ToString();
    }
}   
  public ActionResult Index()
          {
        IDictionary<int, Device> devicesDictionary;
        if (Session["Devices"] == null)
        {
            devicesDictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, Device>();
            devicesDictionary.Add(1, new Lamp(false, "Лампа", BrightnessLevel.High));
            Session["Devices"] = devicesDictionary;
            Session["NextId"] = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            devicesDictionary = (SortedDictionary<int, Device>)Session["Devices"];
        }

        SelectListItem[] devicesList = new SelectListItem[1];
        devicesList[0] = new SelectListItem { Text = "Лампа", Value = "lamp", Selected = true };
        ViewBag.DevicesList = devicesList;
        ViewBag.Text = devicesDictionary[id].Status; // Не могу здесь вывести состояние объекта
        return View(devicesDictionary);
    }
```

Comment: "Не могу здесь вывести ..." - почему?

Comment: [id] студия подчеркивает красным The name 'id' does not exist in the current context

Comment: ну поставьте 0 вместо `id`

Comment: @Igor System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Данный ключ отсутствует в словаре. если поставить 0. Ноль не устроит,т.к. у меня может быть много объектов с разными состояниями. Нужно по id достать объект

Comment: я ж не заставляю "0" использовать - это было для примера. Не нравится 0, поставьте 1. А если серьезно - только Вы знаете, откуда у Вас в коде должен браться этот `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не объявили переменную, о чем вам и пишет студия. Должно быть хотя бы так:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IDictionary<int, Device> devicesDictionary;
    //.. ваш код
    int id = 0; //объявление и инициализация
    SelectListItem[] devicesList = new SelectListItem[1];
    devicesList[0] = new SelectListItem { Text = "Лампа", Value = "lamp", Selected = true };
    ViewBag.DevicesList = devicesList;
    ViewBag.Text = devicesDictionary[id].Status;
    return View(devicesDictionary);
}
```

Comment: Объявление переменной не решает задачу. В таком же проекте на web forms у меня было так          public DeviceControl(int id, IDictionary<int, Device> devicesDictionary)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.devicesDictionary = devicesDictionary;
            Initializer();
        }   А как здесь сделать таким же похожим образом?

Comment: @АнтонЕвсеев ну так посмотри откуда к тебе `id` приходило в формах, будет понятно как сделать так же

Comment: Так же и приходило. Вызывался метод Initialize(). А как реализовать с MVC не пойму. IDictionary<int, Device> devicesDictionary;
        private int id;
        public void DeviceControl(int id, IDictionary<int, Device> devicesDictionary)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.devicesDictionary = devicesDictionary;
            Initialize(); 
        }